# Why is there an `equivalent` value for std::strong_ordering?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

The valid values of [`std::strong_ordering`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cmp#strongord-1) are `less`, `equal`, `equivalent`, and `greater`. However, it appears that `strong_ordering::equivalent` and `strong_ordering::equal` are equal (*i.e.*, interchangeable), since in both cases the exposition-only `value` field equals zero, and there is no other state for the exposition-only constructor to initialize.

It makes sense that `strong_ordering` doesn't have any *separate* `equivalent` value, since equivalent values are always equal when the ordering is strong. But what's the point of making `strong_ordering::equivalent` a synonym for `strong_ordering::equal`, as opposed to not defining it at all?

Comment: It's pretty funny, 'equivalent equals equal'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This allows `C::equivalent` to be defined for all comparison categories `C`. There used to be five of them, all of which had this, now just the three.

If you need something like that, it helps to have it. And it costs nothing to provide, so... there it is.